# Save as pdf intent

Tags: android

The app in the screen is Chrome browser, which intent I should use to launch it with my pdf file?

Basically I want to launch this app with my pdf file.

[image]

Comment: You should go through documentation or research on internet first before asking question.
Go through this documentation. You'll have your answer.

https://developer.android.com/training/printing/custom-docs

Answer (score 1):

Try saving it in a folder in your phone then openning it with you're default PDF viewver or Google Drive. At the top (or bottom depending on the app), in the contextual menu, look for the "Print" option.